# node js Set Interval Method Calling

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I have a doubt regarding the setInterval function. I am trying to read the JSON file and send email to all the email id's within that JSON,But the problem is only the last email id pass to the **sendtheMail()** function. Therefore email send only to the last email id. below you can see my code , Please can anyone help me with this issue

```
async function mailSend(callback) {

    for (let scriptData of automatedScriptData.dataList) {
        var userData = {
            email: scriptData["Business Email"],
            password: "acc0unt@123",
            name: scriptData["First Name"] + " " + scriptData["Last Name"],
            firstName:scriptData["First Name"],
            title: scriptData["Title"],
            timeZone: scriptData["Time Zone"],
            location: scriptData["Country"],
            company: scriptData["Company"]
        };

       setInterval(function() {
         console.log(userData.email);
           sendtheMail(userData);
           }, 5*1000); 

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you even using a `setTimeout` in the first place?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: `var userData` — use `let` there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is single-threaded and it has an event loop

[image]

Your `function` has a cycle and upon each iteration, an event is added to the event loop. However, since `var` variables are [function-scoped](https://dev.to/sandy8111112004/javascript-introduction-to-scope-function-scope-block-scope-d11), the variable is overriden in each iteration of the cycle and then, the `function` you defined in `timeout` is called, but by then your variable has taken its value. Change `var userData` to `let userData`, because `let is block-scoped` and that's what you need here. Sample example to prove my point:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let foo = i;
    setTimeout(function() {console.log("foo is " + foo)}, 100);
}
```